# Track price changes on a daily basis

Tags: mysql

I am trying to track price changes on a daily basis. I have 2 tables `Stores` and `Prices`.

Table `Stores` columns:

- s_id
- company
- address
- city
- state
- zip
- phone

Table `Prices` columns:

- ref
- storeid
- price
- mgr
- datetime

NOTE: storeid in Prices is a reference to s_id in Stores

What I would like to do is run a query to find all prices from yesterday and compare them to today to see if they have changed. Please understand that I am filing in for the database admin for any advice you can offer.

Comment: First you should add a table with your RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ...) You can edit your question and add a table. You can also create a sql fiddle using your RDBMS on http://sqlfiddle.com/. this question contains both tables and sql fidldes sample: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131568/how-can-get-random-2-rows-from-each-group-from-joined-table

Answer (score 2):

Would be something like:

```
select  p1.ref, p1.storeid, p1.price, p2.price
from    prices p1 
join prices p2 on p1.ref = p2.ref
where   trunc(p1.datetime) = trunc(sysdate)
and     trunc(p2.datetime) = trunc(sysdate-1)
and     p1.price <> p2.price;
```

You can add `Stores` to get store information if you need. I do not know which DB you use so I gave a solution for Oracle. The `trunc` function gives you the date part of a date.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, you can use this query:

```
SELECT Pnew.ref
    , Pnew.storeid
    , Pnew.mgr
    , Pnew.price as `NewPrice
    , Pold.price as `OldPrice
FROM prices Pnew
INNER JOIN prices Pold
    ON Pnew.ref = Pold.ref
        AND DATE(Pnew.datetime) = CURDATE()
        AND DATE(Pold.datetime) = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
WHERE Pnew.price <> Pold.price;
```

It supposes that column `ref` is the key.

This query returns `ref` with today's date and an extra column with `CHANGED` or `same`:

```
SELECT Pnew.ref
    , Pnew.storeid
    , Pnew.mgr
    , Pnew.price as `NewPrice`
    , Pold.price as `OldPrice`
    , IF(Pnew.price <> Pold.price, 'CHANGED', 'same')
FROM prices Pnew
INNER JOIN prices Pold
    ON Pnew.ref = Pold.ref
    AND DATE(Pold.datetime) = SUBDATE(Pnew.datetime, 1)
WHERE DATE(Pnew.datetime) = CURDATE()
;
```

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8e190/3/1) works with a small sample of 6 rows. It contains both queries.

Output:

```
ref | storeid | mgr | price | price | 
  1 |       1 |   1 |     1 |     2 | CHANGED 
  2 |       1 |   1 |     3 |     3 | same 
  3 |       1 |   1 |     6 |     4 | CHANGED
```